# Suppose $\dot{x}=Ax$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$. Determine $A$ from the initial and final states

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, system-identification

Two experiments were done:

1. $x(0)= [1,1]^T$ and $x(1)=[4, -2]^T$
2. $x(0)= [1, 2]^T$ and $x(1)=[5, -2]^T$

How can I find the $A$ matrix? I know how to find $e^{At}$, for $t=1$, using these $2$ experiments. If it is not possible, which method can I use to find with more data? Suppose $A$ has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your question and add what you managed to obtain, and while you're at it, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) in all the equations on your post to make things easier to read.

Comment: Do you have to calculate it by hand or can you use computer, like Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

From the given data we can write

$$x(t=1)=\exp(A)x(t=0)=[I+A+1/2!A^2+...]x(t=0).$$

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we know that we can reduce higher powers of $A$ to a linear combination of $I$ and $A$. So we know

$$x(t=1)=[\alpha_0I+\alpha_1A]x(t=0).$$

We have two initial values and final values pairs corresponding to $4$ conditions. But we have $6$ parameters ($4$ parameters in the matrix and the two additional parameters in the linear combination). So it is difficult to determine the parameters in this case.

If you had an additional pair of the initial condition and final condition, you should be able to uniquely determine the coefficients.

For real systems (with noise etc.), we would collect a lot of data $\mathcal{D}=\{(x_1,\dot{x}_1),...,(x_N,\dot{x}_N\}$ consisting of $\dot{x}$ and $x$ samples. Then we would combine them into a matrix formulation

$$[\dot{x}_1,...,\dot{x}_N]=A[x_1,...,x_N]$$

and approximate the system matrix $A$ by $\hat{A}$ using a least squares estimate.

I haven't thought it through but it should be something like

$$\hat{A}=[\dot{x}_1,...,\dot{x}_N][x_1,...,x_N]^T\left[[x_1,...,x_N][x_1,...,x_N]^T \right]^{-1}.$$

Comment: But $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ should be a dependent of $A$, namely they should satisfy its characteristic equation.

Comment: It is clear that they depend on the characteristic equation as we started with powers of A. But adding the direct dependence would not simplify the problem. We could eliminate the additional constants by adding the real dependence on the coefficients of A, but that would not simplify the problem.

Comment: In this case you can calculate it by using the matrix logarithm, see my answer. Though it is not a unique answer mathematically speaking, but there is really only one sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you obtain $e^{A\,t}$ you can use the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Calculating_the_logarithm_of_a_diagonalizable_matrix). This not always well defined and does not have a unique solution, but often one can make some assumptions and still find a sensible answer. The easiest way to calculate this by hand is by using the eigen decomposition of $e^{A\,t}$ (assuming that it is diagonalizable), so

$$
e^{A\,t} = V\,D\,V^{-1},
$$

with $D$ a diagonal matrix and $V$ a matrix containing the eigenvectors. The matrix logarithm can then be obtained by taking the matrix logarithm of $D$, which can be obtained by taking the logarithm of it diagonal elements

$$
\log\left(e^{A\,t}\right) = A\,t = V\,\log(D)\,V^{-1}.
$$

It can be noted that, even if $D$ is diagonal, the logarithm of the diagonal elements is not unique, namely one can always add an integer times $2\,\pi\,i$ to it (due to [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)). However this will most likely make $A$ complex, which often does not make sense for real life systems.

Comment: Your line with $\exp(At)=VDV^{-1}$ is not precise. You have $t$ on the left and no $t$ on the right. Even if $V(t)D(t)V(t)^{-1}$ you will still have $4$ (eigenvector components) + $2$ (eigenvalues) parameters in the representation. You can set up an additional condition that the eigenvectors are orthogonal. As far as I can see the matrix logarithm is also defined by an infinite series. It would be best if you would provide the solution to the given problem, such that we see what you mean.

Comment: It is given that $t=1$, so a constant and not a variable. I will hold off posting the solution for now and see if OP can solve with the steps I have provided.

Comment: You should edit your answer and set $t=1$.

Comment: @MachineLearner This is already stated in the question itself and this way my answer should also work in other cases, so other $t$ and $e^{A\,t}$ (if diagonalizable).

Comment: Please see my initial comment. The left side has $t$ in it. The right side has no $t$. Your answer is inconsistent.

Comment: @MachineLearner But that is just the definition of an eigen decomposition. So given $e^{A\,t}$, find its eigen decomposition, take the matrix logarithm of $D$ and use the "reverse eigen decomposition" to get $A\,t$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $x(1)=e^A x(0)$, so we can write
$$ \begin{bmatrix}4 & 5 \\ -2 & -2\end{bmatrix} = e^A \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, we can easily obtain
$$e^A = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ -2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
which has eigenvalues of $1$ and $2$. Note that $e^A$ has the same eigenvectors with $A$ with $e^{\lambda_i}$ as eigenvalues where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ (Spectral Mapping Theorem). So
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & \ln2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ -2 & -1\end{bmatrix} \ln2$$